# Who is responsible for damages caused by a malfunctioning borrowed machine?

Tags: torts-damages

Example:

I borrow your car and drive it. The brakes on your car fail and I smash the car into someone's gate. Prior to lending the car, the car manufacturer posted a *possible* defect on their web site that said that certain cars brakes *might* malfunction. (If relevant, let's say the manufacturer said that just 3% of cars encountered this problem.) You didn't check the site or know about this defect, and you never had a problem.

Who's responsible to pay damages to the gate?

- Me - If I recall correctly, a *Sho'el* (borrower) may be responsible for any damages that he causes to someone else's property even accidentally.
- You - As car owner, aren't you responsible for checking up on possible manufacturer defects?
- The car manufacturer

**Note:** - Please try to generalize your answer regarding any similar machine or item. The main parameter in this scenario are that the manufacturer had a defect and they publicized it (questionable if a web post is "sufficient"), and that the owner did not know about the defect so assumed that there was none at the time that he lent the item.

Perhaps, in this scenario, more than one party may be responsible for various reasons. E.g., the manufacturer might ultimately be responsible for compensating the car owner for their negligence in insufficiently posting the problem. In this question, I am only interested in who must pay damages to the gate owner.

Comment: Please inform me if this question enters your "complex scenario" rule. As much as I try to read it, I sometimes have trouble knowing what questions qualify and what doesn't.

Comment: Just wondering: Where do we find in halacha that a *seller* is liable for a defect (and especially the damage it causes) that he wasn't aware of at the time of a sale?

Comment: @DanF IMHO The OP is still mistaken. "If I recall correctly, a Sho'el (borrower) may be responsible for any damages that he causes to someone else's property even accidentally." That statement seems incorrect. The special rules of sho'el apply only between the lender and borrower-concerning the borrowed object/animal only; not between the borrower and a third party gate owner(even if it is the lender's gate). IOW a guy who rented a car, borrowed a car, or owns his own car would all be equally liable for the gate owned by a random third party.

Comment: @DoubleAA I was contrasting "accidental "onus" damage" to the car vs "accidental damage" to some other person's property. The OP still seems to be using the word "accident" in that understanding. Yes, of course if the borrowed object gets damaged due to normal use during its normal work purpose, then the borrower does not have to pay. Example: the car's spark plug needs replacing because of the borrower's road trip. That is just wear and tear so he shouldn't pay. The car was legally parked and someone hit it. That is onus and he pays. The OP does not seem to be מתה מחמת מלאכה.

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's a very good question. Regarding cars, there may be a "built-in" responsibility. Most car manufacturers have an x-year warranty for essential car parts. If there's a manufacturer's defect on the part under warranty, do they have a responsibility to contact you about it?

Comment: When you say possible defect posted, do you mean a recall?  The manufacturer has to inform the owner of the car of such a problem, and provide a remedy for it. Who has liability(I think)depends on whether notice has been sent, if your friend didn't get the notice,  or if he didn't fix the problem after being informed of it.  But SOMEONE has liability, and we're Jews, so figure out who, and sue sue sue!

Comment: I wonder if one can say its a grama,hard to say since pushing the gas pedal causes continous motion

Comment: @Gary I agree that the manufacturer prob. has liability for something. But, the gate damage is "indirect". In other words, the manufacturer may have to compensate the car owner for negligence, not for a 3rd party's damage.

Comment: @DanF - I think that's what's called "incidental or consequential damages", and the manufacturer is liable, since their product was faulty, because if the brakes were properly manufactured, it would've never happened.  There HAS to be a lawyer on this site somewhere who can clear this up...!  The warrantee for something like a hard disk drive might say something like "limited to replacement of defective product, but not incidental or consequential damages".  But nobody's actually getting hurt, even though there might be loss of business data.  Backup often!

Comment: 1. **If the malfunctioning is not certain - המוציא מחבירו עליו הראיה.** Especially if only a minor part has it - the Chazokoh is the 97% of all cars function well.The driver pays the damages and then litigates with the lender/manufacturer.

Comment: 2. **If the malfunctioning is clearly proven - it's מקח טעות** - there were no lending/borrowing of the car. I don't recall such a case in the standard Halocho (maybe Shutim).

Comment: Before dealing with the 3rd party, let's ask a simpler question  - **what about the borrower/buyer injuring himself with a clearly malfunctioning object**? E.g. an apartment burned down from a faulty microwave. Anyone familiar with a Sugiyah? Then it is a מקח טעות, but the damage was caused by the person actually activating and using it. Without his usage, the damage was not inflicted.